# What CSS will stop round button displaying with a white square around it?

Tags: css

I downloaded a round button to use as a dialog close image. It looks round, but when I open in Windows Paint I can see it is actually a white square with the round button in it, and when I display it in a browser it shows the white square outline that I don't want. Is there any way to get rid of that?

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/xY9Kp/

```
<body>
    <button id='b1'/>
</body>

#b1 {
background: transparent url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2lu62vUif1sHaq-qhefoWeA2GZ9zBr2j7arVLHdfFTKwcoZSAKA') no-repeat center center;
background-size: 100%;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any constructive input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth adding that your issue is not with CSS. Even though `border-radius` *might* help by simply hiding the white areas, you ultimately need to find an image with a transparent background. There is no way to alter the color of *some* of an image's pixels with CSS.

If you're browsing for icons, look for the ones with a checkered white-gray background -- this means it's actually transparent.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried border-radius and it did indeed help. But I will search for an image with a transparent background as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
border-radius: 12px;
```

should do it